# Visual Studio does not work when started by double-clicking a SLN file

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I just installed Visual Studio (2015) yesterday. I created a Hello World C++ console application in `D:\VsStudio.WS\hello-world` directory.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    printf("It works!");
    return 0;
}
```

It compiled and worked. When I close Visual Studio and open the project by double-clicking the SLN file, Visual Studio complains

> MSB8008: Specified platform toolset (v140) is not installed or invalid. Please make sure that a supported PlatformToolset value is selected.

and cannot compile. Also, IntelliSense cannot locate `SDKDDKHVer.h` and some other files, the `printf()` function is red underlined and gives the “Error: identifier printf is undefined.”

If I close the solution, but keep Visual Studio open, then open the solution using the file menu, the “corrupted” state persists. (I noticed that in this “corrupted” state, the doxygen syntax highlihting works, which it did not before.)

If I close Visual Studio and start it from Windows’ Start menu, then go to the file menu and open the solution, no errors show and the program compiles and executes correctly. However, in this “sane” state, the doxygen syntax highlighting does *not* work, whyever.

Any suggestion what causes such behaviour and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the resaon: There is still an old Visual Studio 2010 installed on my computer. In Windows Explorer, the SLN files were set to be opened with Visual Studio 2010, which, of course, does not support platform toolset (v140). The doxygen syntax highlihting obviously only works in Visual Studio 2010, but not 2015, whyever.

How to fix it:

Right-clicking the solution and selecting open with → choose a different app → Microsoft Visual Studio version selector → check: „always open with this app“ → OK fixes it.